# putting header and image inline in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the following class:

```
<div class="title1">
    <img src="themes/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
    <h5>Name</h5>
</div>
```

in one line by using the following line in the css file:

```
.title1{display: inline}
```

but i still get them in two different lines. 
How can I change it to be inline?

Comment: just use float:left to header and float:right to image

Comment: The `h5` tag is block by default, set it to `display:inline-block` too

Comment: @BilalUsean, no. Just... no

Comment: @BilalUsean it didn't work. I have a paragraph of text after the div element, and I got the header and the image floating by its sides.. I wanted them to be close to each other on the left top of the paragraph.

Comment: @AlonEitan it doesn't change any thing

Comment: @user5948783 the image style is table so that's also will need to change, you have lot's of good answers

Comment: @user5948783 below I paste one code its work for me just try this if not work let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display you image and text inline, you have to change their individual `display` properties; changing the parent's is not enough. The image by default will display inline, but the `<h5>` displays as a block by default, which means it always takes up the full width so it displays on its own line. If you change the `<h5>` to display inline, it will display next to the image. Like:

```
.title1 h5 {
    display: inline; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css applies to your main div "title1" however, you want this to apply to its children. You can test this css :

```css
.title1 > img, .title1 > h5 { display:inline; }
```

```html
<div class="title1">
    <img src="themes/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
    <h5>Name</h5>
</div>
```

However be sure to know that with inline display, you won't be able to set size as easy as inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

The display property specifies the type of box used for an HTML element. I don't think is the right thing for your job. Try :

```
<div>
    <img id = "img" src="themes/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
    <h5>Name</h5>
</div>
```

And css : `#img {float: left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h2{display:inline-block}
img{display:inline-block}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h5>The New</h5>
<img src="themes/images/logo.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

if not work let me know